# How to get the source code for an html page after clicking on a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below html page where the user types in the textarea and clicks on the submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function func () {
  var a = document.querySelector('html');
  var b = document.querySelector('.inner');
  b.textContent = a.innerHTML;
  console.log(a);

  var output =  b.textContent
  var OpenWindow = window.open("child.html", "mywin", '');
  OpenWindow.dataFromParent = output; 
  OpenWindow.init();
}
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>HTML Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" >
<div style='margin: auto; padding: 1em; width: 85%;'>

<p style='color:#3399FF; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px'>Job-specific:</p><br>
<textarea rows="4" style="width:100%">Job-specific</textarea>  </br></br>

<p style='color:#3399FF; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px'>Skills:</p><br>
  <textarea rows="4" style="width:100%">Enter Skills</textarea>  </br></br>

  <div style='clear: both; max-width: 90%; text-align: center;'>
                        <button onclick="func();">Submit</button>
                <pre><code class="inner"></code></pre>
  </div>

</div>

</form>   
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the source code for the above html page open in a new window after the user clicks on the submit button. so far it is generating the source code within the same page and the child.html page is coming empty, also not sure how to get the source code for the html page without the java-script and submit button.

Comment: not sure why this question is getting marked as negative.

Comment: I would wager it's because it looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we dont write code for you.**

Comment: My apologizes I should have stated the question differently, this was because my HTML skills are a bit rusty.

Comment: Negative votes are probably because it seems a mix of lack of apparent research (a google search for "open new window javascript" should give you plenty of results to try and study) and also the question was unclear (open a new window, ok, but what for ?) It seems obvious you probably don't want to open an *empty* window. You are not telling what do you want to show in this window, And also, the question is not describing what is your *goal* ! (hence, the comment about the x/y problem). Also, some basic starting code was missing : you added it, this is good (but maybe not enough to reopen)

Comment: @Pac0 I want to have the source code populated in the new window (child.html) excluding the java script and submit code. I have been searching a lot but I don't seem to find a solution to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function func () {
  var a = document.querySelector('html');
  var b = document.querySelector('.inner');
  b.textContent = a.innerHTML;
  console.log(a);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="func();">GO</button>
<pre><code class="inner"></code></pre>
```

Comment: thank you very much! this is very helpful I am just going to work on making it open in a new page.